# C++ Databind a getter to a field in XAML and a setter to another field in XAML

Tags: c++, xaml, mvvm, managed-c++

This is a amateur question though I am attempting to create a windows8 app using MVVM. I created the ViewModel and have a method with a setter and getter.

Now on my View I have a TextBox such that the value entered needs to be sent to the setter
And also a Textblock such that whatever value the getter returns should populate this textblock

I'm having some trouble setting it up

Attached is the code in my CPP from my VM

Can you please tell me what are my next steps

Apologies if the question seems trivial.

```
String^ MainPageVM::incomeCalc::get() {return m_Name;}
void MainPageVM::incomeCalc::set(String^ value)
{
if(m_Name != value)
{
    int valueInt = MiscMethods::stringToInt(value);

    m_Name = Taxcalculator::calcNetSalary(valueInt).ToString();
    NotifyPropertyChanged("incomeCalc");
}

}

void MainPageVM::NotifyPropertyChanged(String^ prop)
{
  PropertyChangedEventArgs^ args = 
    ref new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop);
  PropertyChanged(this, args);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Never mind I found a solution

I used a TEXTCHANGED Handler on the textbox in the View.
When it changed it will call a method on the VM which effectively then sets the value